# JAX-RS client API: Why is the MessageBodyReader allowed to throw a WebApplicationException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, java-ee-7

According to the Javadoc, the [readFrom](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html#readFrom-java.lang.Class-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.annotation.Annotation:A-javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType-javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap-java.io.InputStream-) method of a [MessageBodyReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) may throw a [WebApplicationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html), which seems strange as this seems only to make sense on the server side when parsing request messages.

But the same classes are also used on client side to parse response messages, which happens after the webservice has been called (which might be successful or not) and thus the readFrom method should not affect the HTTP status code in this case.

So why is the MessageBodyReader allowed to throw a WebApplicationException and how should it be handled by a client?

Eg. jersey-media-jaxb is an example which throws a WebApplicationException:
https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.22.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-jaxb/xref/org/glassfish/jersey/jaxb/internal/AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.html

The question arises since the client implementation provided by Jersey seems to have bug. I filed a related issue here: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-3005